# C unit test framework for CMake

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I'm starting a C project with CMake and I want to use TDD. So I need an efficient unit testing framework which can be integrated with CMake.

I'm looking for a UTF wich can:

1. Be easily integrated with CMake
2. Gives me code coverage
3. Be (if it is possible) BSD-licenced

I have tried Kuya wich matches **3.** but doesn't give a CC, then Check wich matches **2.** but I haven't find any UTF that can be easily integrated with CMake.

By "*easily integrated with CMake*" I mean a tool wich can be launched by `$ make tests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/googletest/ is C++.

It's well integrated with CMake, and I guess that shouldn't be a big problem to have your tests using a bit of C++, even if your tested files are in plain C.

Comment: Testing using C++ *requires* C++-compatible header files (i.e. always check `__cplusplus`, use `extern "C"`, don't use stuff that's invalid in C++, ...) there are many reasons why "use a C++ test framework" is not an appropriate answer IMHO.

Comment: I spent a very long time trying to configure gtest for my C project. According to this issue that I faced, gtest is no longer supporting C. https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/1279

Answer (score 1):

What about CTest? CTest allows you to integrate tests into CMakeLists.txt. See http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest for more thorough explanations. For your for requirements:

1. It can't be more simple.
2. That depends on how you design your tests - ctest only runs them
3. The same license as cmake

Comment: Ctest is not an unit test framework, it is a functionnal test framework, it test the produced executable not each functions.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I edited my answer with a comment to 2).